# Is it possible to create a kafka topic with partiton count 1 if default is 3?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

i am working in a kafka streams application in springboot.we are using Apache kafka with server.properties having **num.partitions=3**

so due to this setting every topic was  getting 3 partitions by default.

but we need to create some topics with 1 partition .

so how we can achieve the above?

**Note:**
From kafka streams application if topic is not available it will create automatically and we are not using  the following bean to create topics

```
 @Bean
  public NewTopic topic1() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("samle").partitions().build();
  }
```

so in this case is there any way to create partition count as per own or anyway to enforce the broker to create particular count of partition form kstream application

Comment: Unclear if you're asking about "user topics" or "internal topics"... If you have no beans, then you have auto topic creation enabled on the broker, which should really be turned off, and there are so many other ways to create a topic that's different than the broker default settings

Comment: Thanks  @OneCricketeer it's all about user topics only ,and we have enabled the auto topic creation enables for now ,so is there any other way to create topic automatically with certain count of partition from springboot application  any configuration is available for that?

Comment: No, Spring has no such configuration to create topics unless you create that config mapping yourself into a Bean like you've shown... What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: Actually @OneCricketeer we are having nearly 25 topics to be created from application if we need use the below code `@Bean
  public NewTopic topic1() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("samle").partitions().build();
  }` then we need to have the same block 25 times right ,so only we are not using this and let the kafa streams will create the output topic while processing the input topic

Comment: You could create your topics outside of the application... It's only done once, anyway

Comment: i am not using spring-cloud-stream  @GaryRussell we are working in normal kafka streams application using spring boot application by having spring-kafka dependency alone

Comment: Sorry; mis-read; deleted.